# Undefined Index when creating array

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, undefined

I'm getting an error.  Undefined Index when trying to call $distance[$newkey] (one UI error for each combination of keys).
What am I doing wrong?  Keep in mind I'm new to programming, so keep it very simple.  I won't understand jargon.  Thanks.

```
<?php

Require_once 'Work-Cell-Scheduler/WCS/os.php';

$NumSuppliers=5;
$NumDepts=5;

//capacity
$capacity=array();
for($i=0;$i<$NumSuppliers;$i++){
    $capacity["S{$i}"]=rand(400,600);
}
$totalcapacity=array_sum($capacity);
//print_r($capacity);
$demand=array();
for($i=0;$i<$NumDepts;$i++){
    $demand["D{$i}"]=rand(300,550);
}
$totaldemand=array_sum($demand);
//print_r($demand);

if($totaldemand>$totalcapacity){
    echo "random problem is infeasible";
}
$profit=array();
foreach($demand as $key => $value){
    $profit[$key]=rand(20,40);  
}
//print_r($profit);

$distance=array();
foreach($profit as $key => $value){
    foreach($capacity as $k => $v){
        $newkey = "{$key},{$k}";
        $distance[$newkey]=rand(1,9);
    }
}
//print_r($distance);

//total profit = profit - cost of transportation (distance)
$tprofit=array();
foreach($capacity as $key => $value){
    foreach($profit as $k => $v){
        $newkey="${key},${k}";
        print_r($distance[$newkey]);
        $tprofit[$newkey]= $v - $distance[$newkey];
    }
}
//print_r($tprofit);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last `foreach` loop,

```
$tprofit=array();
foreach($capacity as $key => $value){
    foreach($profit as $k => $v){
        $newkey="${key},${k}";
        print_r($distance[$newkey]);
        $tprofit[$newkey]= $v - $distance[$newkey];
    }
}
```

The correct one is :

```
$tprofit=array();
foreach($capacity as $key => $value){
    foreach($profit as $k => $v){
        $newkey="{$key},{$k}";
        print_r($distance[$newkey]);
        $tprofit[$newkey]= $v - $distance[$newkey];
    }
}
```

You were assigning wrong string to `$newkey`. Try it now, and update your question if more errors pop up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is line:

```
$tprofit[$newkey]= $v - $distance[$newkey];
```

You make calculation but variable

```
$distance[$newkey]
```

is not set.

You should check if $distance[$newkey] is set using:

```
if (isset($distance[$newkey])) {
  // .. one task
}
else {
 // .. another task
}
```

In your case it should probably be:

```
if (isset($distance[$newkey])) {
  $tprofit[$newkey]= $v - $distance[$newkey];
}
else {
 $tprofit[$newkey]= $v;
}
```

Comment: This code removes the error; however, the output for $tprofit = $profit (looped about 5 times though)  so if $profit=(1,2,3), $tprofit=(1,2,3,1,2,3,...1,2,3).  How can I make this subtraction work?  could I put the code that creates the $distance array within the loop?

Comment: You should simple think about your application logic